# Creating a global helper file for CodedUI tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, global, coded-ui-tests

I'm writing out a CodedUI Suite of automated tests for our integrations and the project structure will look something like this:

```
SolutionName
  CodedUITest1
    Properties
    References
    CodedUITest1.cs
    HelperFile1.cs
    HelperFile2.cs
    UIMap.uitest
  CodedUITest2
    Properties
    References
    CodedUITest2.cs
    UIMap.uitest
```

The two helper files in the CodedUITest1 project are public to only that project and cannot be accessed within the CodedUITest2 project.

I tried creating a new solution folder and having everything under there but still couldn't gain access.

Is there an easy way to create a global file which can be accessed throughout any project under my main solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are your CodedUI Tests stored in separate projects? To me this seems like a very bad idea unless you're testing something like 2 different applications and want to separate the tests that way. One project per test is crazy.

Even once you consolidate the tests into one project or even if you don't, your testing utility files should probably be stored in a separate project. If I had my druthers this is what a good solution looks like:

```
Project Solution
    Unit Testing Project
        UnitTestClass.cs
    CodedUI Testing Project
        CodedUITests.cs
        CodedUIMap.uitest
    Testing Utilities Project
        HelperFile1.cs
        HelperFile2.cs
    Database Project
        Insert whatever here
    Services Project
        your web services
    Web Project
        Your View and Controller files etc.
```

Your unit and CodedUI projects reference your Testing Utilities Project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did a slight variation of what you had mentioned.  The only thing I can't do is store the CodedUI project with the main application project.  But I was able to create a helpers project and reference those files.  So thank you!

Comment: I faced the same restriction when I was tasked with writing CodedUI tests as well. It makes things like Continuous Integration testing a bit more difficult but also provides some advantages. Good luck!